# Error: Control may reach end of non-void function - cat function

Tags: c

```
char *wcat(char *str, size_t n, FILE *fp){

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("wcat cannot open file\n");
        fclose(fp);
        perror("File cannot be opened");
        return NULL;
        exit(1); 
    }else{
        if ((str = fgets(str,n,fp)) != NULL){
            printf("%s",str);
            return str;
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Terminal:

```
gcc -o wcat wcat.c
Error: wcat.c:36:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

The fp already equals fopen(...).

I am not sure why this is happening. I wanted to create this wcat file to work like:

```
./wcat file1.c file2.c
```

Comment: Handle the else case of the second if statement.

Comment: The `if` statement in the `else` may not execute the body of the `if` and that then leaves the function to return — but no value is returned.  Note that `return str; exit(0);` is silly; the `exit(0);` will not be executed.  Similarly with `return NULL; exit(1);`.

Comment: The function is not coherently designed.  The function that calls `fopen()` or equivalent should check the validity of the pointer.  This function should not.  All else apart, the function that calls the open function knows the file name and can give a better error message, quoting the file name.

Comment: What do you mean by calling `exit(0);` right after `return str;`? There's no way you'll get to that `exit`.

Comment: What does `wcat()` do?  Does it print the contents of the first file to standard output, and then the contents of the second file?  If so, you need a loop in the `else` clause to repeatedly read lines and print them.

Comment: Another note on the coherency of the function, if you are taking a `FILE*` as a parameter -- it should have been opened and validated in the caller. (I can see some interim function calls where that wouldn't apply, but in general...) Similarly, if you are not calling `fopen` in the function, then the `fclose` would presumably be handled by the caller as well. Scattering different pieces of an operation into separate unrelated functions is a recipe for disaster. Keep a logical approach to where events are handled -- it makes them much easier to keep track of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following changes, with comments, is the correct way to handle this function:

```
char *wcat(char *str, size_t n, FILE *fp){
    // note: this check should have been handled 
    // where/when 'fopen()' was called
    if (fp == NULL) {
        // this changes the value in 'errno' 
        // so 'perror() will not display the right message
        //printf("wcat cannot open file\n"); 
        //fclose(fp);         // <-- never open'd so cannot close
        perror("File cannot be opened");
        return NULL;
        //exit(1);            // <-- will never be executed
    }else{
        if (fgets(str,n,fp)){
            printf("%s",str);
            return str;
           //exit(0);        // <-- will never be executed
        }
        return NULL;         // <-- need to handle when 'fgets()' fails
    }
}
```

after applying the corrections AND moving the check for a failure of 'fopen()', the code would look like the following:

```
char *wcat(char *str, size_t n, FILE *fp)
{
    if ( fgets( str, n, fp ) )
    {
        printf("%s",str);
        return str;
    }
    return NULL; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your else clause also needs an `else`, or at least a default return. Your `if`s don't cover every possible case. The warning says exactly what the problem is.

```
char *wcat(char *str, size_t n, FILE *fp){

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("wcat cannot open file\n");
        fclose(fp);
        perror("File cannot be opened");
        return NULL;
        //exit(1); 
    }
    else if (fgets(str,n,fp))
    {
        printf("%s",str);      
        return str;
        // exit(0);
    }

    return NULL; /// or whatever it is that you expect to happen here.
}
```

*Neither* of the calls to `exit` makes sense. They'll never be executed. It *looks* like you're trying to use those to return some sort of success/failure flag, but:

1. they never execute because they follow a `return`
2. `exit` terminates the program.

The parameter is passed back to the calling process. In my experience, this is basically never used unless you're writing a console utility.

Do you really understand what `exit` does? And `return`?

There's a lot wrong with this one. I suggest stepping through in your debugger.

Comment: `if (fp == NULL)`, no use `fclose(fp);`, just `return NULL;`, the `str=` part isn't needed either. You can just `if (fgets(str, n, fp)) printf ("%s", str); return str;` at that point as well.

Comment: Also, note that `nullptr` is a C++ concept — it is not yet a part of C (but it might be a part of C2x).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good call - I didn't read that tags. Considering just deleting this. There's a lot wrong with the code.

Comment: You can move the `return str;` out of the `else if` (which you can simply turn into an `if(...)`) as if `fgets()` fails, `str` will be `NULL` which can serve as the `return` on its own. `:)`

Comment: It is hard to criticize coherently that which is not coherent to start with.  Nevertheless, you've raised some good points, and there are a couple more you can act on if you wish.  I don't see a need to delete your answer.

Comment: No need to nuke it, just keep making it better.